# Run code in parallel from single datasource

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I wrote a sparkjob which takes data from hdfs in parquet format. 
Now I want to distinguish the executed code based on the devicetype and execute for each device owner. When looking at the logs the code is executed sequentially instead of in parallel. I tried different #workers #cores amount of ram combinations without an change in execution time.

In my head it should be possible to have n*m parallel executes where n is the amount of devices and m is the amount of owners since data is not connected in any way between those.

Code in general looks like this

```
df = readFromParquetHDFS    //contains data for every device and every owner

dfTypeA = df.where($"device" === "TypeA")
  df_analysis = doStuff(dfTypeA)     //analysis happens per device
  array_owner.foreach(owner => {
    df_owner = df_analysis.where($"owner" === owner)
    spark.writeToMysql(df_owner)   //writes to mysql table DeviceA_OwnerA
  })

 dfTypeB = df.where($"device" === "TypeB")
  df_analysis = doDifferentStuff(dfTypeB)
  array_owner.foreach(owner => {
    df_owner = df_analysis.where($"owner" === owner")
    spark.writeToMysql(df_owner)
  })
```

Is parallelism achievable with spark in this kind of way or do I need to start a seperate job for each device or even each device for each owner.

Comment: Maybe you should look for a RDMS which does query parallelising it self like PostgreSQL..

Comment: Sadly I don't have any other option than using mysql as my result database

Comment: *"Sadly I don't have any other option than using mysql as my result database "* Fair enough i would figured that but still i wanted to make that suggestion *"When looking at the logs the code is executed sequentially instead of in parallel."*  i assume the start timings are really together ? As it takes take to parse the SQL optimize it and run it which can take up to a few seconds when alot off joins are involved in the query

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand with spark : if you use Dataframe or RDD objects, the data will be distributed on your executors, in order to parallelize the transformations on your object.
You have to understand the notion of partition with spark.
The parallelism with spark : it is to be able to separate a big dataframe in partitions, distributed on the executors, which will carry out the transformations on these partitions to improve the processing performance.